# How to address an array with double-curly braces

Tags: javascript, playwright, playwright-java

I am working with testing and accessing credentials from an array called "creds" that contains a set of 15 username/password pairs.

```
[
{user: 'user', password: 'password'}
{user2: 'user2', password2: 'password2'}
.......
]
```

This code grabs the first set of values in the array:

```
//if there are no credentials left to be used, wait and check 
again.   If not, return the first credential in the array. 
while (creds.length === 0) {
    // Wait for 100 ms and check again
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 100))
    }
    // Dequeue a credential and return it
    return creds.shift()
```

What is returned by this is:

```
{ { username: 'username', password: 'password'} }
```

The problem is that I can't access them using the array.username/array.password method, because of the extra curly braces around them.  How do I get this to either NOT add/return the object with the extra curly braces, or access the values inside regardless of the curly braces.

currently, trying to use array.username/array.password just returns undefined.

Comment: Note that the second block of code you're showing is "a single object, inside of a block scope", so: what is the code that returns this? And given that you can't pass blocks around, what is the _real_ form you're getting this in, and what does the code that does that look like?

Comment: I'll assume the syntax error in the first one was simply a typo in the question.  For the second one... What specifically is producing this result?

Comment: This doesn't look like Java. Why is it tagged [tag:playwright-java]? I don't see that the Playwright tags are relevant. This just looks like a question about basic JavaScript objects. Please share a complete runnable [mcve] so others can understand the problem and help. Thanks.

Comment: If you have an array of `Object` then `shift()` should return either one of those `Object` instances or `undefined`. It should not return a "double-curly brace" thing, as that is not something that happens in JavaScript.

Comment: I tagged it with playwright because this is being used in a playwright test to access credentials for logging into the site being tested.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you, in working on this I have liberally used console.log statements to check to see what's coming back and happening.  

The original array is correct, and when the code I added above returns the credentials (in the '.shift()' statement, that's what I get back, with the extra set of curly braces.  '

Comment: @DanWalker: If all of this is happening in JavaScript code then can you update the question to include a [mcve] as a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193) which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: There's no JavaScript object that gets logged with double curly braces. Curly braces are only used for objects, and object contents are always `key: value` pairs.

Comment: @DanWalker Not sure what to tell you, but there is no way a shift on array `[{user: 'user', password: 'password'},{user: 'user2', password: 'password2'}]` will return `{ { username: 'username', password: 'password'} }` in javascript.

Comment: The only possibility I can think of is that this is a class with a custom `toString()` method that prints this way. What does `Object.getPrototypeOf(array)` return?